# google map is not centered in fancybox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox, fancybox-2

I was looking and trying an entire day but couldn't find one right solution for this problem. The part I need to be centered is always top left in FF and IE, Safari seems to be more bottom left...

this is all code you need to try, copy, paste and click...

big screen is good to see the problem doesnt looks to bad on small screens

thanks for help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".google_iframe").fancybox({
            'width'             : '75%',
            'height'            : '75%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="google_iframe" href="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=202414688179067925321.0004d62815a849d23c081&amp;t=h&amp;ll=43.36373,16.508332&amp;spn=1.617251,3.364563&amp;output=embed">
    click here for fancy
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4E3p/)

Comment: thanks for jsFiddle Brian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be created when you try to pre-load the fancybox `iframe` (default value is `true`). As a workaround just disable `iframe` pre-loading within your fancybox custom script like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.google_iframe').fancybox({
        // 'autoScale'    : false, // not valid in v2.x, use autoSize instead
        // 'transitionIn' : 'none', // not valid in v2.x, use openEffect instead
        // 'transitionOut': 'none', // not valid in v2.x, use closeEffect instead
        width      : '75%',
        height     : '75%',
        autoSize   : false,
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        type       : "iframe",
        iframe     : {
           preload : false // this will prevent to place map off center
        }
    });
});
```

... **notice** that I commented out some API options for v1.3.4 that are not valid in v2.x

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy8F8/)** ... or full page see http://jsfiddle.net/Sy8F8/show/lite/, then you can compare it with your full page (not centered) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4E3p/show/lite/)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know about the preload:false... How could I found out this with just googleing, didn't find this information at fancybox?

Comment: @caramba : just for the record, the option is in the fancybox [documentation](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) however it doesn't specify when to use it ... since  working with iframes has its flaws I guess this is why this option was included. PS."Caramba" in Spanish means "oh gosh".

Comment: JFK thanks for your answer!also didn't know about the spanish meaning of my name, caramba just sounds funny :-)

Comment: Hi. Note: it doesn't work without 'autoSize:false'. So it's neccesary to have 'iframe:{preload:false}' and 'autoSize:false' to center map in fancybox.